# Is it possible to prioritize threads in time sliced multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

Given 2 threads running simultaneously on a one core machine.
Is it possible in Java to prioritize one thread over the other in a sense such that for every time slice a thread is run, thread one has 75% chance of getting the slice and slice two only 25%?

I have tried by setting the priority of the thread but then thread one just gets to finish first and thread two is only started afterwards.

Comment: I doubt you're going to get exact desired ratios as far as time-based multiplexing. To some extent it will depend on the operating system as well. However, you could try starting the two threads with different priorities. Give each thread a `LinkedBlockingQueue` of `Runnables` that they `take()`. Then, have the main thread add a `Runnable` to each of the two thread's queues one right after another and see what happens..

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize Thread object with a number from 1(lowest) to 10(highest. Threads with higher priority are more likely to be allocated processor time before lower-priority threads, but without any grantee.

You can defined a `ThreadFactory` which starts thread with certain priority, and use it with Executors. This one just takes priority from a queue

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class PriorityThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final Queue<Integer> priorities;
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        final var thread = new Thread(r);
        final var priority = this.priorities.remove();
        thread.setName(String.format("Priority: %d", priority));
        thread.setPriority(priority);
        return thread;
    }
}
```

If you run start a couple of threads with that:

```
class HeavyComputation implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() { new Random().ints().max().getAsInt(); }
}
final var factory = new PriorityThreadFactory(10, 1);
factory.newThread(new HeavyComputation()).start();
factory.newThread(new HeavyComputation()).start();
Thread.currentThread().join();
```

Over the time you will notice that thread with higher priority consuming sligthly more CPU time:

```
$ jstack -l `pgrep -f Test` |grep Priority
"Priority: 10" #13 prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=571668.65ms elapsed=573.02s tid=0x00007f3990652000 nid=0x2f8a80 runnable  [0x00007f397793d000]
"Priority: 1" #14 prio=1 os_prio=0 cpu=560930.84ms elapsed=573.02s tid=0x00007f39906bb000 nid=0x2f8a81 runnable  [0x00007f397783c000]
```